# Why my absolute positioned element affects the page size?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create an designed element which I want to float on the edge of my right corner of the screen,

and I want only to show half of it,
while the other half I'm trying to place outside of the screen.

I'm trying to do that with position absolute, but from some reason it enlarges my screen instead of just placing the element outside the edges.

what is it that I'm missing?

```
<div class="app-wrapper" style="position: relative;">
    <div class="half-hidden-element" style="
        position: absolute;
        width: 41.875vw;
        height: 41.875vw;
        left: 100%;
        background-color: black">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not affect the page size you overflow the width of the div containing the element

you will have to manage it by using overflow css property

```css
.app-wrapper {
  border: solid red;
  height: 25px;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="app-wrapper" style="position: relative;">
    <div class="half-hidden-element" style="
        position: absolute;
        width: 41.875vw;
        height: 41.875vw;
        left: 100%;
        background-color: black">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I used "overflow-x" instead since I wanted it to be only hidden by the right corner and to enable downward scrolling in my website.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you need `body { overflow: hidden }` and a proper calculation to move half the element outside the right side of the viewport.

Properties `left,right,top,bottom` depict a location relative to the parent size, not the `position: absolute` element itself. If you want 50% of element `.half-hidden-element { width: 41.875vw }` outside the parent you need to displace it with `41.875 / 2 = 20.9375`

- `left: calc(100% - 20.9375vw)`
- `right: -20.9375vw`

The snippet shows next to this solution a solution using CSS *custom properties*. I added a few bordered elements (need `body { overflow: auto }`) to check the final calcuations.

```css
/* Makes borders part of total element size */
* { box-sizing: border-box }

body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden /**/ }

.app-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.half-hidden-element {
    position: absolute;

/* Solution with hardcoded values */
/* Assign either left or right, not both */
/*
    width: 41.875vw;
    height: 41.875vw;

    left: calc(100% - 20.9375vw);
    right: -20.9375vw;
*/

/* solution using custom properties */
    --size: 41.875;

    width : calc(var(--size) * 1vw); /* 1vw = 1% of current viewport width */
    height: calc(var(--size) * 1vw);

    /* Half size, moved right with negative value */
/*  left : calc(100% - var(--size) / 2 * 1vw); /* either */
    right: calc(var(--size) / 2 * -1vw);       /* or     */

    background-color: black;
}

/* Just to check correct positioning (needs body to overflow) */
.half-hidden-element { display: flex }
.lft { width: 50%; height: 100%; border: 1px solid red }
.rgt { width: 50%; height: 100%; border: 1px solid green }
```

```html
<div class="app-wrapper">
    <div class="half-hidden-element">
        <div class="lft">L</div>
        <div class="rgt">R</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="app-wrapper" style="position: absolute;">
<div class="half-hidden-element" style="
    position: fixed;    width: 41.875vw;    
    height: 41.875vw;    
    left: 75%; 
    background-color: black">
</div>
```

Comment: By changing the position of the parent to Absolute and child to Fixed. Relative makes the element float next to the parent.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?